# Already freed memory

Tags: c, free

Is there any way in C to know if a memory block has previously been freed with free()? Can i do something like...

```
if(isFree(pointer))
{ 
    //code here
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Ok if you need to check whether a pointer has already been freed you may want to check your design. You should never have to either track reference count on a pointer or if it's freed. Also some pointers are not dynamically allocated memory so I hope you mean ones called with malloc(). This is my opinion but again if you have a solid design you should know when the things your pointers point to are done being used.

The only place I have seen this not work is in monolithic kernels because pages in memory need  a usage count because of shared mappings among other things.

In your case simply set unused pointers to NULL and check that. This gives you a guaranteed way of knowing in the case that you have unused fields in structures that were malloced. A simple rule is wherever you free a pointer that needs to be checked in the above way just set it to NULL and replace isFree() with if pointer == NULL. This way no reference count needs to be tracked and you know for sure if your pointer is valid and not pointing to garbage.

Comment: I thought I was gonna catch some flak for this guess not :)

Comment: In theory I agree with your answer, but you offer no constructive specifics for how to go about creating such a design.

Comment: I can't really tell him what to do if I don't know what he's doing.

Comment: +1 I wish I could give more than one vote. This `You should never have to either track reference count on a pointer or if it's freed.` is so true.

Comment: @Rudy thanks I don't see it as much in C as I do in Obj-C where people are actually checking the retain count and then doing release loops 0_0

Comment: I see a lot of problems in Delphi and people checking pointers all the time, and even nilling them out when there is no need (e.g. in the last line of a destructor). I am constantly telling people that proper design makes all this unnecessary, but they call it "defensive programming" and tell that without it, their program crashes. Aaaaaaargh! ;-)

Comment: FWIW, I haven't seen the release loops yet, but that is hilarious! And people won't accept it if you tell them their design could be improved (i.e. it sucks) either. Usual reply: " but it works!" <g>

Comment: @Dave: proper design that makes checking pointers or counting references manually unnecessary is something one could write an entire, long article or even a thin book about.

Comment: @Rudy: that's correct and there are plenty of books out there yet people still try and do it :\

Comment: @Rudy: absolutely.  So maybe a good answer to the question would recommend such an article or book.

Comment: @Rudy: no, I don't.  If I did I would have posted my own answer.  Honestly, having done very little serious programming in C, I do not know good techniques for handling this issue myself, which is why I say that I don't find this answer very helpful.

Comment: Such practices are the same for almost all non-GCed programming languages, be they C, C++, Objective-C or Delphi, just to name a few.

Comment: @Dave: One thing you have to understand is that I can't sit here and redesign his application for him, mostly because I don't have the time and second because I don't know what his design is. It's hard to tell people what to do concerning this without telling them to rewrite a lot of things.

Comment: Guys, I've got to disagree: there is no way you can avoid this *in C*.  See the example in my update: because one commonly is malloc-ing structures that contain pointers to malloc-ed memory, C programmers always need to have a disciplined way of dealing with this.  This is why `free(NULL)` is defined to always succeed.

Comment: @Charlie, I'd have to disagree with you; it can ALWAYS be avoided. If you have malloced structures that contain malloced memory you can always check for NULL before calling free, personally I think free(NULL) shouldn't succeed but that's just me. Checking if a pointer is valid should never have to be done and it just radiates bad design as it shows that you're not sure when your structures are even usable or not.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way.

You can, however, use a little code discipline as follows:

Always *always* **always** guard allocations with malloc:

```
void * vp;
if((vp = malloc(SIZE))==NULL){
   /* do something dreadful here to respond to the out of mem */
   exit(-1);
}
```

After freeing a pointer, set it to 0

```
free(vp); vp = (void*)0;
/* I like to put them on one line and think of them as one peration */
```

Anywhere you'd be tempted to use your "is freed" function, just say

```
if(vp == NULL)[
    /* it's been freed already */
}
```

#### Update

@Jesus in comments says:

> I can't really recommend this because as soon as you're done with that
>   memory the pointer should go out of scope immediately (or at least at
>   the end of the function that releases it) these dangling pointers
>   existence just doesn't sit right with me.

That's generally good practice when possible; the problem is that in real life in C it's often not possible.  Consider as an example a text editor that contains a doubly-linked list  of lines.  The list is really simple:

```
struct line {
    struct line * prev;
    struct line * next;
    char * contents;
}
```

I define a `guarded_malloc` function that allocates memory

```
void * guarded_malloc(size_t sz){
    return (malloc(sz)) ? : exit(-1); /* cute, eh? */
}
```

and create list nodes with `newLine()`

```
struct line * newLine(){
    struct line * lp;
    lp = (struct line *) guarded_malloc(sizeof(struct line));
    lp->prev = lp->next = lp-contents = NULL ;
    return lp;
}
```

I add text in string `s` to my line

```
lp->contents = guarded_malloc(strlen(s)+1);
strcpy(lp->contents,s);
```

and don't quibble that I should be using the bounded-length forms, this is just an example.

Now, how can I implement deleting the contents of a `line` I created with the `char * contents` going out of scope after freeing?

Comment: I can't really recommend this because as soon as you're done with that memory the pointer should go out of scope immediately (or at least at the end of the function that releases it) these dangling pointers existence just doesn't sit right with me.

Comment: but still +1 for malloc guarding :)

Comment: also global pointers to objects (null checking is fine with me if it's a list/queue etc) but passing around things that you know can be freed out from under you without reference checking and such seems off

Answer (score 3):

I see nobody has addressed the reason **why** what you want is fundamentally impossible. To free a resource (in this case memory, but the same applies to basically any resource) means to return it to a resource pool where it's available for reuse. The only way the system could provide a reasonable answer to "Has the memory block at address X already been freed?" is to prevent this address from ever being reused, and store with it a status flag indicating whether it was "freed". But in this case, it has not actually been *freed*, since it is not available for reuse.

As others have said, the fact that you're trying to answer this question means you have fundamental design errors you need to address.

Comment: Fundamental design errors, like music to my ears. Gonna need to use that one from time to time

Answer (score 1):

For a platform-specific solution, you may be interested in the Win32 function [IsBadReadPtr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-isbadreadptr) (and others like it). This function will be able to (almost) predict whether you will get a segmentation fault when reading from a particular chunk of memory.

Note: IsBadReadPtr has been deprecated by Microsoft.

However, this does not protect you in the general case, because the operating system knows nothing of the C runtime heap manager, and if a caller passes in a buffer that isn't as large as you expect, then the rest of the heap block will continue to be readable from an OS perspective.

Pointers have no information with them other than where they point. The best you can do is say "I know how this particular compiler version allocates memory, so I'll dereference memory, move the pointer back 4 bytes, check the size, makes sure it matches..." and so on. You cannot do it in a standard fashion, since memory allocation is implementation defined. Not to mention they might have not dynamically allocated it at all.

On a side note, I recommend reading '[Writing Solid Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1556155514)' by Steve McGuire. Excellent sections on memory management.

Comment: No one should ever use IsBadReadPtr. For anything.

Comment: @Zan: Added note that it has been deprecated. Just pointing out the the possibilities :)

Comment: I have that as a StyleCop rule, if you use IsBadReadPtr, it's a compile error :)

Answer (score 1):

In general the only way to do this portably is to replace the memory allocation functions.  But if you're only concerned about your own code, a fairly common technique is to set pointers to `NULL` after you `free()` them, so any subsequent use will throw an exception or segfault:

```
  free(pointer);
  pointer = NULL;
```

Comment: Actually, since the libc `free` can be called on null with impunity (the Single Unix Specification says, "If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action shall occur."), your `my_free` should also be designed that way, for minimal surprise.

Comment: @Chris: yes, `free()` _can_ be called on null, but in practice I've never written code that expects to do that.  In general, freeing unallocated memory is something you don't want to do in your own code, and it's helpful to be told if it happens, especially during development/debugging.

Comment: That's probably the only simple and effective way to avoid a double free on a pointer. The free function should have been designed to take a pointer to your pointer (void **) and set it to NULL automatically after freeing the memory. And don't tell me that writing 0 to the pointer would impact the performance. Think at the impact of not setting the pointer to NULL. A language should be never error prone. Of course we are talking about a language born almost 50 years ago so I wouldn't expect such commodities.